# OpenCV Draw Image over webcam

Tags: python, opencv

I followed a tutorial to put a rectangle around a detected face on the webcam. It works really good, but I want to draw an image like this: [image: mask] over the face. How can I do this? [Code](https://github.com/shantnu/Webcam-Face-Detect) (I am running the opencv3 version)

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37198079/3962537) out for inspiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I used this where frame was the webcam and x_offset and y_offset were the offsets from the face track function.

```
s_img = cv2.imread("iron.jpg")
    l_img = frame
    l_img[y_offset:y_offset+s_img.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+s_img.shape[1]] = s_img
```