# Python CV2 choose alpha of mask to make it transparent

Tags: python, numpy, opencv3.0

I want to  make the mask which I append to an image transparent in some way. I have the following:

img_background[mask]=[0,5,255]

I want to have the mask region ([0,5,255]) transparent.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082300/how-to-create-a-transparent-mask-in-opencv-python

Comment: Thanks, I can try using an RGBA image instead of RGB

Answer (score 1):

You can add the two images using cv2.addWeighted like this:

```
import cv2

background = cv2.imread('field.jpg')
overlay = cv2.imread('dice.png')

added_image = cv2.addWeighted(background,0.4,overlay,0.1,0)

cv2.imwrite('combined.png', added_image)
```

Credits:
[Using openCV to overlay transparent image onto another image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image)